# "Il y a une grande activité [diurne | nocturne | crépusculaire]"... Si nous étions à l'aube, quel mot désignerait ce moment dans cette phrase ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Je voulais écrire à un parent qu'avec cette canicule, en me promenant à 6 heures du matin, j'avais déjà croisé beaucoup de monde.

À un autre moment de la journée, j'aurais écrit :

- il y a une grande activité diurne,
- il y a une grande activité nocturne,
- il y a une grande activité crépusculaire...

Mais c'était l'aube. Comment la désigner ?

Il y a une grande activité _______.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En plus de l'excellent *matutinal* cité dans une autre réponse, on peut mentionner *auroral*, qui désigne ce qui a trait à l'aurore.

Answer (score 5):

Faute d'adjectif spécifique, je dirais :

> *Il y a une grande activité **dès le petit matin**.*

Sinon, tu peux essayer le très rare *matutinal*, un synonyme de matinal souvent associé à l'aube :

> *Il y a une grande activité **[matutinale](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/matutinal)**.*

voire tenter un néologisme :

> *Il y a une grande activité **[potron-minét](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/potron-minet)ale*** ;-) (*dès potron-minet*)

Comment: ou alors "Il y a une grande activité aux aurores".

Comment: @Graffito Pourquoi pas, ou alors "Il y a une grande activité le matin aux aurores".

Comment: J'aime beaucoup ce "potron-minétal". C'est très dardesque.

Answer (score 0):

Au lever du jour? Au lever du soleil? Il n'y apparemment pas d'adjectif antonyme de *crépusculaire*, malheureusement. Il y aussi la très classique *aurore aux doigts de rose*, puisqu'on en est aux périphrases. En tout cas, je dirais simplement (et tant pis si ce n'est pas un adjectif):

*Il y a une grande activité à l'aube déjà*.